# Overriding children of abstract classes

Tags: dart

I have created an abstract class:

```
abstract class Foo {
    void stuff();
}
```

If I extend the abstract class, should I use `@override` to annotate it?

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    @override     // is including this line good practice?
    void stuff() => print('Stuff done.');
}
```

I'm conflicted here:

- I'm not actually defining `stuff`'s behavior in `Foo`, so there's no functionality being overriden.
- When `extend`ing in other OO languages it's usually convention to include the `@override`, even on previously undefined methods in abstract classes.

What is best practice? Is there an existing convention?

Comment: you mean while extending abstract class, do we need to use override annotation for the overridden methods or not? is that correct? @user

Answer (score 0):

The `@override` annotation indicates that `void stuff()` overrides a method from a superclass or interface.

Adding `@override` has no effect on runtime, but it can influence static analysis.

The analyzer can produce warnings, notifying you that you don't actually override as you intended or override by accident by adding these linter ruler to `analysis_options.yaml`

```
linter:
  rules:
    - annotate_overrides
    - unnecessary_overrides
```

Comment: All correct. Whether to use the `@override` annotation depends on what the project you are working on prefers. Many projects do use `@override` as a rule, but it's not part of the language, and it's not mandated by the Dart style guide. If you do want to use `@override` in general, then yes, you do want to use it here. The `@override` is used for implementing interface methods, not just overriding implementation, and the abstract member becomes part of the superclass interface.